# How to get the output an infinite running command in Rust

Tags: rust

When someone just wants to get the output of a simple command like `ls`, then one can write like this:

```rust
let output = Command::new("ls")
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .output()
    .unwrap();

let stdout = String::from_utf8(output.stdout).unwrap();
```

However, if I want to get the output of an infinite running program like `http-server`, it won't stop until I kill it manually. So if I use the method above, my project will stuck there forever. How should I do for such situation? More specifically, how to get the output of the first five seconds, or the first five lines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `.stdout(Stdio::piped()).spawn().unwrap().stdout.unwrap()` and read from it. If you want to read the first five lines, use a `BufReader` and `BufRead::lines()`. The first five seconds is more tricky, you'll either need to do the reading in a separate thread, or read nonblocking.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b6e105ac5bce2d88fa9db2f3571ef702)